# Can I hide the upper menu "SuiteNavWrapper" inside a single modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-pages, customization

I want to hide the SuiteNavWrapper inside a single sharepoint modern page.. so is this possible?

[image]

I added a modern script editor web-part, and i added this custom CSS:-

```
#SuiteNavWrapper
{display:none;}
```

but this will not hide the `SuiteNavWrapper`.. i think this is because the `SuiteNavWrapper` is not within the page context.. so not sure if there is any other approach i can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John,

I have a test your CSS code on an SPO page, it results that the CSS is overridden by other styles. You may have a try below workaround:

[image]

BR

Comment: seems this is working .. not sure if will stay working in the future,, but atleat for now it hide the SuiteNav.. thanks

Comment: @JohnJohn :  don’t use in-page CSS.  Use my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

No, manipulating the DOM, especially the SuiteNav, is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Append this query string to the page’s url:

```
?env=Embedded
```

The above works for *Modern* SharePoint pages

For *Classic* SharePoint pages, append the below to the page’s url:

```
?IsDlg=1
```

[Also, See Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290113/isdlg-1-in-modern-sharepoint)

***Up-vote or Mark as Answer if this helped you!***