# IsDlg=1 in Modern SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

This is an issue that has bothered me for a while since migrating our organization to the Modern SharePoint UI in SharePoint Online.  In *Classic SharePoint* pages - both on-prem and online - appending the following query string to the page's URL will hide the Page Header and Nav Bar:

```
?IsDlg=1
```

***Is there a functional equivalent in *Modern SharePoint* Pages, Lists & Libraries?***

| Before ***?IsDlg=1 in URL*** | After ***?IsDlg=1 in URL*** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before IsDlg=1 In URL] | [image: After ?IsDlg=1 in URL] |

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, evidently there *is* a functional equivalent for Modern SharePoint Pages, Lists & Libraries.
By appending the following query string to the URL of a Modern Page, List or Library, the Page Header and Nav Bar are removed:

```
?env=Embedded
```

SP Lists Example:
https://***{YourTenant}***.sharepoint.com/Lists/***{YourListName}***?env=Embedded

SP Document Library Example:
https://***{YourTenant}***.sharepoint.com/***{YourDocumentLibraryName}***?env=Embedded

SP Individual page example:
https://***{YourTenant}***.sharepoint.com/***{Site Pages}***/awesome-page.asps?env=Embedded

***See Table Below***

---

Also, there is another query string you can use to ensure that the Suite Bar is rendered, but it only works with Modern SharePoint *Pages* - not Lists or Libraries.
If used on Lists or Libraries in Office 365, this query string will automatically redirect the user to the Microsoft Lists Application render of the List or Library requested:

```
?env=WebViewList
```

---

| Before ***?env=Embedded*** in URL | After ***?env=Embedded*** in URL |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |