# How I can completely remove the Modern page Banner/Title inside my communication site, similar to the modern pages inside the look-book?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, communication-site

Inside the SharePoint Lookbook sites, most of them do not have the Modern page Banner/Title, as follow:

[image]

While when I tried to add a new modern page inside my communication site, I will always get a Page Banner/Tile, as follow:

[image]

So how I can completely remove it? I know that I can set the banner as Plain, but this will still show the title text, while I need to remove the whole section.

Any advice?

Comment: Peep the answer here:
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290113/isdlg-1-in-modern-sharepoint?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C54.7449](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290113/isdlg-1-in-modern-sharepoint?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C54.7449)

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz using the `?env=Embedded` is totally different thing, as it will render the page without the navigations.. while i only need to remove the page banner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a blank page without header & title, you have to create a site page with `Home` page layout.

Check this step by step article to create a modern blank page without header & title in SharePoint online: [SharePoint Online: Create a blank page without header & title](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/26/sharepoint-online-create-a-blank-page-without-header-and-title/)

---

**Update**:

If you have already created the page, you have to change the page layout to "Home" page layout using PowerShell.

Using PnP PowerShell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "<site-url>"  
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "MyPageName" -LayoutType "Home"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but in my case i already have created the page and its content. so can i remove the Title/Banner for an existing page or i will need to recreate the whole page?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t - just get used to it.
There are a lot of things I and my users had to get used to the interface.
Don’t have such a thin skin about modern UX.

Comment: i am not sure i totally get your point.. can you explain it in more details please?